# Synchronizing Parent & Child process

Tags: c, unix, synchronization, systems-programming

I want to synchronize the parent and child process to alternatively print 1 to 10 into a file. And output which process printed the number. The following code prints alternatively, but the same number. Please help me out!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MSGSIZE 16
int parent= 1;
int n=-1;
main ()
{
  int i;
  char *msg = "How are you?";
  char inbuff[MSGSIZE];
  int p=0;
  FILE *fp1,*fp2;
  pid_t ret;

  ret = fork ();
  if (ret > 0)
    {
      i = 0;
      while (i < 10)
    {

      n++;
     // sprintf(msg, "%d", n);
     // fp=fopen("abc.txt","a");
     // write (p[1], itoa(n,msg,MSGSIZE), MSGSIZE);
     // sleep (2);
    // fclose(fp);
      //read (p[0], inbuff, MSGSIZE);

    fp1=fopen("abc.txt","r");
    fscanf(fp1,"%d",&n);
    fclose(fp1);
    fp1=fopen("abc.txt","w");
     fprintf(fp1,"%d",n); 
    printf("Parent: %d\n", n);
      i++;
    fclose(fp1);
    sleep(2);

    }
    exit(1);
    }
  else
    {
      i = 0;
      while (i < 10)
    {

      n++;
      //sleep (1);
     // read (p[0], inbuff, MSGSIZE);

     fp2=fopen("abc.txt","r");
     fscanf(fp2,"%d",&n);
     fclose(fp2);
     fp2=fopen("abc.txt","w");

     fprintf(fp2,"%d",n);        
      printf("Child: %d\n", n);
           i++;

     sleep(2);

    }
    }
  exit (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because processes don't share memory, so basically your `n` is different for each process. For this you need to use `inter-process-communication`, which Linux provides several methods to do it:

http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html

In general you just need to find a way to share the value of `n` among the parent and child process.

Note: With user threads this issue doesn't appear, because user threads on the same process share memory. You just need to synchronize the access to it. Also, be careful because depending on the method you use with processes you might also need to synchronize access.

Answer (score 0):

If u are thinking to change the same memory location of the variable, then it will not be possible because both the processes have different address space. The same thing u can achieve in case of threads.